# How to add extra View after 3 position RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, position

I want to add advertisement View after RecyclerView 1,2,3 position and then advertisement View and then RecyclerView 4,5,6 position and then advertisement View and then 7,8,9,10,11... How to handle position to add extra 3 RecyclerView?

Comment: You dont want to do that. You want to use another ViewHolder for ads

Comment: [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Answer (score 0):

No no.. don't nest your recyclerview.. use multiple ViewHolder with different layout..

Override getItemViewType with your desired config

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      return items.get(position).getType();
}

@Override
       public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
          View view = null;
          switch (viewType) {
              case ITEM:
                  view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_a, parent, false);
                  return new ATypeViewHolder(view);

              case HEADER:
                  view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_b, parent, false);
                  return new BTypeViewHolder(view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Fuction Like That To see If position After 3 Or Not
and I realy Dont Sure CurrentP % 3 != 0 OR CurrentP % 3 != 1

```
private IsAfrerTree(int position)
{
   int CurrentP = position+1;
   if(CurrentP % 3 != 0)
      {
      return true; 
      }
   else
     {
     return False;
    }
}
```